# How to find the maximum point of a function with four dimensional variable.

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

There is a very complicated non-concave but smooth enough function $f(X)$, where $X=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$. I want to find the maximum point of $f$ on a constrained set as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}max  & & f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\\ s.t & & 0<x_1\leq 0.5\\ & & 0<x_2\leq 0.2\\ & & 0.5\leq x_3\leq 12\\& & -1\leq x_4\leq 1.\end{eqnarray}
As f is not concave, I even can not prove the uniqueness of the maximum point. Here is what I am doing, but I doubt there is some problem.

Step1: I assume the value of $x_3$ and $x_4$ are known, then I can take the first derivative of $f(x_1,x_2)$ to get optimal $x_1(x_3,x_4), x_2(x_3,x_4)$ explictly. Luckly, when I vary the value of $x_3,x_4$ the optimal $x_1(x_3,x_4)$ always stays in $(0,0.5]$ and $x_2(x_3,x_4)$ always stays in $(0,0.2].$

Step2: I range the value of $x_3$ from $0.5$ to $12$ and range $x_4$ from $-1$ to $1$ with grid size $\Delta=0.01$. At each grid point, I find the optimal $x_1(x_3,x_4)$ and $x_2(x_3,x_4)$ by step1, and calculate the corresponding function value $f(x_1(x_3,x_4),x_2(x_3,x_4), x_3,x_4)$.

step3: Compare the function value at each grid point in step2, choose the grid poin with maximum function value. The corresponding value of $ x_1(x_3,x_4), x_2(x_3,x_4),x_3,x_4$ are the coordinates of maximum point we are looking for.

Is there any problem of this idea? We know that when the optimal maximum point does not locate on the boundary, the corresponding first derivative must be $0$. I calculated it in matlab as above steps, but when I check the first derivative of $f$  at the optimal point I found(it locates inside the domain), it is not $0$.

Comment: Why not compute the entire profile $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ via numerical optimization in matlab? Why the other steps? Also: in step 1 you calculate the "optimum" via the first order condition, but if your function is not concave, then this approach need not yield a maximum - maybe that is what causes the problem. In principle it should be fine to find the optimal values of $x_1,x_2$ as functions of $x_3,x_4$ and then vary $x_3,x_4$ to find a global maximum, but again it need not be valid to find those $x_1,x_2$ via first order condition.

Comment: I'm curious to see why it's possible to solve the problem once you fix $x_3$ and $x_4$. I'm assuming that the resulting problem is convex. In any case there are solvers for global optimization that work fairly well on small simple problems like yours (assuming f is not super nasty). Try BARON on [NEOS](http://www.neos-server.org/neos/).

Comment: @Nameless  yes, find it ergodically.  Here I fix $x_3, x_4$, then it becomes a convex funtion for $x_1, x_2$ so that I can solve $x_1, x_2$ uniquely.  Then I range $x_3, x_4$ ergodically to find the maximum point in $R^4$.

Comment: @wonko  $f$ itself is not convex.  I fix $x_3, x_4$ so that the function$f$ is a convex funtion for $x_1,x_2$. I can use classical method to find the optimizor $x_1(x_3,x_4), x_2(x_3,x_4)$. Then I range $x_3, x_4$ ergodically so that I can find the optimal $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ numerically. Do you think it makes sense?

Comment: @Shine, like Nameless mentioned, you are maximizing $f$, so even if it is convex in $x_1$ and $x_2$, first order methods might not yield a global maximum.